# Blazor - Internal Server Error when running in IIS windows server 2012

Tags: iis, blazor, webassembly

When I run my Blazor WASM locally on IIS it works perfectly. But when I do it in a windows server 2012 R2 and I call it from my computer it gets stuck at "loading..." and I get a "500 (Internal Server Error)" for blazor.webassembly and blazor.boot.json
I cannot test it directly on the server since it has only internet explorer which is not compatible.

[chrome developer tools printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmQ74.png)

I have followed different tutorials, so I have already installed "URL rewrite" and the "Windows Hosting Bundle Installer".
Any idea what to try next? I have been searching in forums for two days now.

Comment: Check the security or login you are using on sever to deploy on IIS. Normally 500 errors has to do with many things but based on my experience it has to do with Windows security.

Comment: It has a problem loading `blazor.boot.json`.  Check if you deployed it at all. And if IIS allows json files.

Comment: That `Unexpected token '<' ...` is a typical NOT FOUND error for the Blazor Hosted model.

Comment: In Chrome's Network tab, see what exactly is the 500 response from server side (the whole error page). That's much more important than just "Internal Server Error". All the guesses at this moment are unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!
blazor.boot.json is present, and IIS allows json.
One additional piece of info I can find is when trying to access the file with the browser on the server
then I get: Handler "JSON" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list so it starts to look as a ASP.NET problem

Comment: It may be ASP.NET framework got corrupted, you can try to reinstall it and try again.

Comment: Ok, finally "fixed" it by using a windows server 2016. I do not know if the 2012 was too old or if there was a problem with permissions. Nevertheless I got tired of trying to fix it and on this new server it is all working. Thanks for the answers!